# Render react component from global js script

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a global script that right now looks at clicks and shows a `confirm` message to let the user know they are leaving our secure site and going to another which may or may not be. (Note: this is for requirements and not up to me).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function interceptClick(e) {
        const target = e.target;
        const hostName = window.location.hostname;
        if (target.tagName === 'A') {
            const href = target.getAttribute('href');
            if (href.indexOf(hostName) === -1) {
                const r = confirm("Warning message....");
                if(!r){
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

What I want to do is display an existing component.

The component I have is...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Modal} from 'react-bootstrap';

export default class Warning extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state ={
        showModal : false
    };
}


open() {
    this.setState({
        showModal : true
    });
}

close() {
    this.setState({
        showModal: false
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <Modal show={this.state.showModal} onHide={this.close.bind(this)}>
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
                <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>
                <h1>Body</h1>
            </Modal.Body>
        </Modal>
    );
}
}
```

Instead of calling `confirm("Warning message...");` Is it possible to render that component from there? Or just change the state?

Answer (score 2):

if your component is exported properly and React and ReactDOM are included per `script` tag, you can use

```js
ReactDOM.render(
    React.createElement(Warning),
    document.body
);
```

In that case you have to use [React without JSX](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-jsx.html), when you want to use it within your HTML file.

---

Alternative way, use the function within your bundle.

```js
function interceptClick(e) {
    const target = e.target;
    const hostName = window.location.hostname;
    if (target.tagName === 'A') {
        const href = target.getAttribute('href');
        if (href.indexOf(hostName) === -1) {
            ReactDom.render(
                <Warning></Warning>,
                document.body
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I was missing the script tag when I tried that earlier. But this doesn't seem like the right way to be doing things, I don't think. Is there a better way to achieve what I'm doing?

Comment: You can use a bundler like [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) and include your function to render your Warning and just can use JSX.
I will update my answer

Comment: Yeah everything gets bundled, and I have a script that imports that bundle, but I'm getting undefined messages still. My script tag is something like `<script src="~/js/appBundle.js"></script>`

Comment: What exactly is undefined and when do you get it?